# How to fix Bootstrap Carousel flicker/flash/blink on Iphones when it transitions to the next item? (Video example included)

Tags: html, jquery, iphone, carousel, flicker

I'm working on a website that has a two carousels for mobile screen sizes. It works perfectly fine on ALL devices except SOME iphones. I have no idea whats causing the issue and none of the devices where its happening are within a 300 mile radius of me, so I can't even debug it. Has anyone run into this issue or know a fix for it?

Again, its important to note that this is only happening on SOME iphones.

Here is a video of whats happening:
https://youtu.be/8XGMKTpUUrI

Here is the html, css, and js code, respectively.

```js
$("#mobileCarousel").carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$("#mobileCarousel").on("touchstart", function(event){
        var xClick = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    $(this).one("touchmove", function(event){
        var xMove = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) > 3 ){
            $(this).carousel('next');
        }
        else if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) < -3 ){
            $(this).carousel('prev');
        }
    });
    $(".carousel").on("touchend", function(){
            $(this).off("touchmove");
    });
});

$(".carousel carousel-item").each(function(){
  var minPerSlide = 3;
  var nextElement = $(this).next();
  if(!nextElement.length){
    nextElement = $(this).siblings(":first");
  }
  nextElement.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i = 0; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
    nextElement = nextElement.next();
    if(!nextElement.length){
      nextElement = $(this).siblings(":first");
    }
    nextElement.children(":first-child").clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
    display: block;

  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid carousel-container d-lg-none d-xl-none">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="mobileCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-sm-2">
              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="code icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">&ltHTML&gt and CSS3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">We design and program your website from scratch and to
                    your liking. No restrictive templates! Have the website you have always dreamt of for your business.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-sm-2">
              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="shield icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">Online Security</p>
                </div>
                <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">Tropiweb supplies SSL security certificates to every
                page it produces. Keep your transactions and clients' sensitive informations out of the wrong hands.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-sm-2">
              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="search icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">Search Engine Optimization</p>
                </div>
                <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">We optimize your web-page's &ltmeta&gt, &ltalt&gt, and
                  &lttitle&gt tags in order to maximize the probability of potential clients finding you through any search engine</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-sm-2">
              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="responsive icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">Sleek and Responsive</p>
                </div>
                <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">Your website is designed with cross-platform compatability as a priority.
                  No matter the web-browser or device (tablet, laptop, or phone) your page will always function properly.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-sm-2">
              <div class="card index-card border-success">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <img src="money icon.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <p class="pTagsForCardTitles">E-Commerce Solutions</p>
                </div>
                <p class="pTagsForCards d-flex justify-content-center">Run your online shop right from your very own website. Validate transactions,
                  keep stock of your merchandise, charge applicable sales taxes, and ship your product with no hassle.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mobileCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span>
              <img class="carousel-arrow-right" src="flecha-de.png" alt="">
            </span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mobileCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span>
              <img class="carousel-arrow-left" src="flecha-iz.png" alt="">
            </span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many sleepless nights and debugging the heck out of it, turns out that the problem was that I was using old versions of Bootstrap and jQuery lmao. As soon as I included the most recent versions of jQuery and Bootstrap the page started behaving exactly as expected in all versions of IOS.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is caused by your use of columns `<div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-sm-2">` inside a container that has no `.row` class right before.
You're using the `row` class just after the container, at the very top which is messing up all the carousel items.

Comment: Hey,  @amarinediary. In case you were curious, the issue was caused by my usage of NOT the newest versions of jQuery and Bootstrap. As soon as I incorporated the most recent versions of the library/framework, it worked perfecty.

Comment: Great to know! Gl with the rest!

Answer (score 0):

i've made a mirror copy of your website http://tropiweb.net/. I've edited your `<div id="mobileCarousel">`
Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/amarinediary/pen/pogedwy
This should be working (not tested). don't hesitate to come back to me if you have any other problem. gl.

Comment: Man, i tried this, but it still does the exact same thing that it does on the video. Weird thing is it does it on the iphone 5s, X, and XI Pro, but not on the 6S or 7... any idea?